# SQL Server- Get all column names in the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table name as `'tblOrder'`, having three columns. I would like to print the column names.

[image: tblOrder]

I want a script that should return a result as:

```
OrderId Name OrderTrackingNo
```

Comment: If you know the column names why do you need to query them?

Comment: @dale-k, Asked by Interviewer.

Comment: As an interview question you really should be having a go yourself and posting your attempt - it won't help you to have someone else did it for you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tblOrder')
```

Try this

Comment: It is showing system column name as well.